# Remove commits with given e-mail

Tags: git

Well, during git setup somehow I have accidentally set my password as my e-mail. That was like a week ago, and there are like 20 commits with it.

I tried to change them following this: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info#changing-the-git-history-of-your-repository-using-a-script
But there is now a copy of every commit that was affected but with the correct e-mail.

This is my personal project, so changing its git history is not that big of a deal.

Comment: If you're still very early in the project, as it seems you are, you might be better off starting a whole new repository. By design, It's notoriously difficult to remove information from a git repository entirely.

Comment: And also you should change your password.

Comment: Yeah, I know, already changed it, thanks for the reminder. I have thought that it will be hard to do and given that I am in fact early in the project, I think I really just start a completely new repository.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)?